# how to calculate total sum and maximum used screen count in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

How to calculate the total count with respect to enabled date and maximum used screen count with its name

My Input table

```
Date        Name        Id  Count   Screen  Enabled Date
03-01-2020  Karthikeyan 1   4       Login   03-01-2020
03-01-2020  Karthikeyan 1   3       Logout  03-01-2020
05-01-2020  Karthikeyan 1   6       Logout  03-01-2020
05-01-2020  Sumit       2   9       Login   05-01-2020
05-01-2020  Sumit       2   5       Logout  05-01-2020
```

My code is

```
enabledDateSummary = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZE(
                enabledDate,
                enabledDate[Id],
                enabledDate[Name],enabledDate[Enabled Date]
            ),
        "TotalCount", CALCULATE( SUM( enabledDate[Count] ), FILTER(enabledDate, 
        enabledDate[Date] = MIN(enabledDate[Enabled Date])),
        ALLEXCEPT(enabledDate, enabledDate[Enabled Date], enabledDate[Name])), 
        "ScreenCount", CALCULATE( MAX( enabledDate[Count] ), 
        ALLEXCEPT(enabledDate,enabledDate[id]) )
    ),
    "Screen",
    VAR CurrentCount = [ScreenCount]
    RETURN CALCULATE( MIN(enabledDate[Screen]), enabledDate[Count] = CurrentCount )
)
```

Output is

[image]

Expected Output table

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using **SUMX()** function instead of **SUM()**

**enabledDateSummary**

```
enabledDateSummary = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                enabledDate,
                enabledDate[Id],
                enabledDate[Name], enabledDate[Enabled Date]
            ),enabledDate[Enabled Date] <> DATE(1970,01,01)
        ),
        "TotalCount", CALCULATE(SUMX(FILTER(enabledDate, 
        enabledDate[Date] = enabledDate[Enabled Date]),[Count])), 
        "ScreenCount", CALCULATE( MAX( enabledDate[Count] ) )
    ),
    "Screen",
    VAR CurrentCount = [ScreenCount]
    RETURN CALCULATE( MIN(enabledDate[Screen]), enabledDate[Count] = CurrentCount )
)
```

**enabledDateSummary Output:**

[image]